# Erro em fazer um Insert no banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando salvar alguns dados no banco e estou recebendo esse erro:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Ocorrencias_dbo.Alunoes_AlunoId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-CEF01-20140410111235", table "dbo.Alunoes", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

O que acontece é que tenho dois models em minha aplicação: Alunos e Ocorrências(1-n). O relacionamento está certinho, o que acontece é na hora de inserir uma ocorrência me gera esse erro ai em cima. No model de ocorrência, tem que escolher o nome do aluno pra dar a ocorrência a ele, e eu acho que é ai que da o erro, vou colocar a action de create e edit pra ficar mais claro. O que acontece é que ele tenta inserir o Id do aluno, e no caso estou inserindo o nome dele. Enfim, estou meio confuso e queria a ajuda de vocês.

Actions:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome");
        return View();
    }
   
    // POST: /Ocorrencias/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Tipo,Causa,Descricao,AlunoId")] Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome", ocorrencia.AlunoId);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // GET: /Ocorrencias/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);
        if (ocorrencia == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome", ocorrencia.AlunoId);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }

    // POST: /Ocorrencias/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,Tipo,Causa,Descricao,AlunoId")] Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(ocorrencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.AlunoId = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "Id", "Nome", ocorrencia.AlunoId);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
```

E quase ia me esquecendo. Estou usando uma biblioteca chamada ASP.net Awesome e nela, on de tem esse Select List ai, eu substitui pelo Helper que tem nessa biblioteca chamado Lookup, que é um popup com uma lista de todos os dados do banco. E para ele funcionar precisa colocar um outro controller dentro da classe pra que ele funcione. Então aqui, vou inserir o controller do Lookup e a view como que ta. Outra coisa que percebi é que, tenho que implementar uma lógica pra salvar e pra editar os dados, pois teria que vir carregados os campos com os dados já cadastrados.

## Códigos

AlunoLookupController:

```
public class AlunoLookupController : Controller
{
    private EntidadesContext db = new EntidadesContext();
    public ActionResult GetItem(int? v)
    {
        var o = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == v) ?? new Aluno();

        return Json(new KeyContent(o.Id, o.Nome));
    }

    public ActionResult Search(string search, int page)
    {
        search = (search ?? "").ToLower().Trim();
        var lista = db.Alunos.Where(f => f.Nome.Contains(search)).ToList();
        return Json(new AjaxListResult
        {
            Items = lista.OrderBy(f => f.Nome).Skip((page - 1) * 7).Take(7).Select(o => new KeyContent(o.Id, o.Nome)),
            More = lista.Count() > page * 7
        });
    }
}
```

Então explicando esse código: GetItem -> ele pega o item escolhido pelo usário e popula o campo com o valor escolhido. Search -> Ele procura pelos dados no banco pra colocar na lista pro usuário escolher.

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Ocorrencia</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tipo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tipo)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Causa, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Causa)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Causa)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlunoId, "AlunoId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @* @Html.DropDownList("AlunoId", String.Empty)*@
            //Aqui o helper que abre um popup com a lista de todos os dados do banco pro usuário escolher !
            @Html.Awe().Lookup("Aluno")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlunoId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o Html que é gerado:

```
<div class="awe-lookup-field">
<input name="Aluno" id="Aluno" type="hidden" class="awe-lookup">
<div class="awe-cdisplay">
    <div class="awe-display">
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="awe-btn awe-openbtn">
    <span class="awe-icon awe-icon-win">
    </span>
</button>
</div>
```

Lembrando que pra num ficar extensa a pergunta eu ocultei algumas partes do Create.cshtml

Comment: Galera, é smeio urgente, será que alguém poderia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera eu resolvi. O que acontece é que eu tenho um relacionamento onde pega a FK AlunoId que é a referência a tabela alunos... Para que o Asp.Net Awesome funcione precisa que onde ta no helper *@Html.LookupFor("Aluno")* seja igual ao controller que faz a manipulação, ou seja, dessa forma: *AlunoLookupController*. Para resolver o meu problema tive que colocar Ao invés de Aluno, no helper e no controller, AlunoId, que seria a referência exata que estava antes e que é a referência a tabela. Então os códigos ficariam assim:

## Controller

```
//Onde está AlunoIdLookup, estava Aluno...., então mudei e ficou como esta abaixo
public class AlunoIdLookupController : Controller
{
   //Aqui vai as actions 
}
```

## View

```
 .....
 @Html.Awe().Lookup("AlunoId")
 ......
```

Pronto, resolvido o problema.
Para quem quiser saber mais sobre a biblioteca Asp.Net Awesome o [site é esse aqui](http://aspnetawesome.com/). Eu acho ela muito funcional, mas tem lá suas peculiaridades. Enfim, a resposta é essa !

Answer (score 2):

O erro significa que `AlunoId` não está definido. Como já dito em outras respostas, sua View precisa ter uma das duas coisas:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlunoId)
```

Ou então

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AlunoId, ((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Alunos).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = option.Nome, 
    Value = option.AlunoId.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.AlunoId == Model.AlunoId)
}, "Selecione...")
```

Pra atualizar o `hidden` use o seguinte na sua View:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name='NomeDoCampoQueObtemAlunoId']").change(function () {
                $("input[type='hidden'][name='AlunoId']").val(this.value);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Ta ai Cigano, caso queira usar a biblioteca, eu achei ela bem legal !